# Recursively scanning a set into a map

Tags: java, recursion

Ok, so I have the following code which iterates over a Set and adds the length of the word as the key and the word to the value which is a TreeSet value. Now I am really bad at recursion and somehow need to reproduce this code to do the exact same thing via recursion. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public static TreeMap<Integer, TreeSet<String>> getWordLengthMap(
        TreeMap<Integer, TreeSet<String>> theReturnMap,
        Iterator<String> theWordSetItr) {
    //Change to recursion, not while loop
    while (theWordSetItr.hasNext()) {
        String newWord = theWordSetItr.next(); //get word
        int lengthOfWord = newWord.length(); //get length
        if(theReturnMap.containsKey(lengthOfWord)) {
            theReturnMap.get(lengthOfWord).add(newWord); //if key exists add value to set
        } else {
            TreeSet<String> newSet = new TreeSet<String>();
            newSet.add(newWord);
            theReturnMap.put(lengthOfWord, newSet);
        }
    }
    return theReturnMap;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to use recursion?  Is it a classroom requirement?

Comment: @ajb Agreed.  Iteration is the better way of doing it.

Comment: Yes it is a class requirement and I want to see how recursion translates this directly

Comment: Lol and here comes the down votes?

Comment: Start trying. This is not a free homework service. Besides, if you have difficulties understanding your assignment, what will you learn from delegating that work to others?

Comment: It's sort of a bummer of a classroom requirement because this really does not lend itself well to recursion at all. But as a hint: `getMap(map, iter) { if hasNext then iter.next(), add word to map, and getMap(map, iter), else that's it }`

Comment: I have tried, or else I wouldn't be here. I get recursion in more basic forms but not when it comes to what I am doing here.

Comment: Thank you @JasonC for actually putting some valuable input in, instead of just flaming for needing help.

Comment: The trick is to come up with a base case and a recursive case. Everything else comes from there. You've got a base case: build(map, no words) = no changes, just the map. And you've got the recursive part: build(map, words) = current word + build(map, rest of words). So you're set. For example computing 2^n recursively: f(0) = 1, we know, that's the base case. And f(n) = 2 * f(n-1) [for positive n's only of course]. And that's it, magic.

Comment: @JasonC "Does not lend itself well to recursion" is an understatement.  I've seen lots of recursion questions on StackOverflow that come from classroom assignments, and this is one of the worst I've seen.  I'm beginning to seriously question whether students should be taught recursion until they need it for, say, sorting algorithms and trees.

Comment: @ajb I agree. When I was in school, we didn't even touch recursion in CS until *after* induction in math, and then we jumped straight into SML, where it was just sort of necessarily part of the routine. By the time we were in algorithms courses and such with declarative languages, the skill was already developed, and we didn't really spend much time on it explicitly. Although, I did take a more theoretical and abstract math-y track out of a few options.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to change much to make it recursive. Just change `while` to `if` and put the recursive call at the end of the `if`.

```
public static TreeMap<Integer, TreeSet<String>> getWordLengthMap(
        TreeMap<Integer, TreeSet<String>> theReturnMap,
        Iterator<String> theWordSetItr) {
    if (theWordSetItr.hasNext()) {
        String newWord = theWordSetItr.next();
        int lengthOfWord = newWord.length();
        if (theReturnMap.containsKey(lengthOfWord)) {
            theReturnMap.get(lengthOfWord).add(newWord);
        } else {
            TreeSet<String> newSet = new TreeSet<String>();
            newSet.add(newWord);
            theReturnMap.put(lengthOfWord, newSet);
        }
        return getWordLengthMap(theReturnMap, theWordSetItr);
    }
    return theReturnMap;
}
```

By the way, in Java 8 this "grouping" operation is way easier to do with the Stream API, specifically by using [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-). This is a more advanced topic.

```
TreeMap<Integer, TreeSet<String>> theWordLengthMap =
    theWordSet
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            String::length,
            TreeMap::new,
            Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new)
        ));
```